# What's the meaning of the "key" symbols in Altium?

Tags: pcb, altium, eda

I'm routing a PCB board with Altium. Today I find when my mouse hover on the pads, it shows some shadowed "key" symbols. What's the meaning of them?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The **"key"** symbol means that the **specific track/pad/component** is in locked position, so it is unmovable. 
Right click on the [specific item \$ \longrightarrow \$ properties \$ \longrightarrow \$ uncheck **locked** checkbox] and the **"key"** symbols will be gone.